# Ошибка при импорте CSV файла в DataFrame из ZIP

Tags: python, pandas, csv, обработка-данных, zip

Я пытаюсь импортировать CSV файл в DataFrame, но сам CSV файл находиться в zip (помимо нужного файла в zip находиться много других CSV файлов).

Я сначала использую `zipfile`, потом `pd.read_csv`:

```
import zipfile
import pandas as pd
archive = zipfile.ZipFile('C:\Python\Controller-gsm_radio-R4V12.20.20-20211027165128-41.zip', 'r')
txtdata = archive.read('GExternalGsmCell.csv')
asd = pd.read_csv(txtdata, sep=',')
print(asd)
```

Но мне выдают ошибку:

> Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оберните `txtdata` в `io.BytesIO`, чтобы получить ожидаемый Pandas `file-like object`:

```
import io

asd = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(txtdata), sep=',')
```

или без создания дополнительной переменной:

```
asd = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(archive.read('GExternalGsmCell.csv')))
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)